# How to know if two graphs are ismorphic or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

For example in the picture above.

I know that I need to calculate if both graphs have the same number of vertices and edges.

But I don't know what I should do next to check if the graphs are isomorphic or not.

Comment: The original title reminded me of [this story](http://mathoverflow.net/a/53905/7206).

Answer (score 5):

Graph isomorphisms preserve the vertex degree, that is, the number of edges incident to a vertex. In $G'$, the vertex $w_5$ has degree $5$, but there is no vertex with degree $5$ in $G$. Thus, the graphs cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: There are *many* more obstacles to an isomorphism visible in these graphs: While both graphs have exactly one double edge and in both graphs the endpoints of this double edge have exactly one neighbour in common, this common neighbour is of degree 3 in the left graph and of degree 2 in the right graph ...